# how do I add a .jsp page in Eclipse and Heroku?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, heroku

I'm new to Heroku and Eclipse and I'm trying to add a .jsp page to my project.  In Eclipse I copied a page that's working and pasted it as a new page in the same folder, but when I try to see this new page  I get an error page, "Oops, something went wrong..."

This page works,

```
http://localhost:8080/sfdc/contacts
```

but this page fails,

```
http://localhost:8080/sfdc/newpage
```

The .jsp files are in the same folder.

Is there something I need to do to add the page beside create the .jsp file?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/sfdc/contacts` request is mapped through the [ContactsController](https://github.com/heroku/template-java-spring-sfdc/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/controller/ContactsController.java).  You might be able to make a request to `/sfdc/newpage.jsp` where you have `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/newpage.jsp`.  But if that doesn't work you might have to create a controller that does the mapping or make a Spring config change.

Comment: Aha!  My class needed this line,
    @RequestMapping("/newpage")

That solved it.  Thanks!